# Why is $m = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

My question applies to graph questions in general.
Given that the equation for a straight line is $y=mx+c$, wouldn't it be easier to calculate the value of a gradient using algebra:
$$ \frac{y-c}{x}=m $$
instead of using the formula $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$? It just seems unnecessarily complicated and also requiring more than one data point when the gradient of a line can be calculated using only the coordinates of one point.

Ex:
[image]
Let's pick one data point on this line, like $(1,4)$. We also know that the y-intercept is 1. If we substitute this into our formula we get $\frac{4-1}{1}=3$ which is in fact the gradient of this line. Why should we go to the trouble of using multiple data points?

Comment: "*Let's pick one data point ... We also know that the y-intercept is ...*" There you have your two points already. A line is defined by two points, and knowing just one point is not enough.

Comment: A line has the form $y=mx+c$. If you know both a point and $c$ , you can of course insert all to get $m$. Otherwise , you need TWO points (not multiple points) to determine $m$. As mentioned, knowing $c$ means knowing a second point and the alternative method is not significantly easier.

Comment: Let suppose that line $y=mx+c$ passes through $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ with $x_2\neq x_1$. Then $y_1=mx_1+c$, $y_2=mx_2+c$. Let express $c$ from first equation and put into second equation: $c=y_1-mx_1 \Rightarrow$ $y_2=mx_2+y_1-mx_1 \Rightarrow$ $y_2-y_1=mx_2-mx_1=m(x_2-x_1)$ $\Rightarrow m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$. This was answer for header question. About your way of calculation: it is essentially the same method with $x_1=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula
$$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$
is defined for any points of the linear graph that exist (either the point is intercept at x-axis or y-axis). Your formula is surely correct given that point $(0,c)$ for y-intercept or $(b,0)$ for x-intercept will gives :
$$m=\frac{y_2-c}{x_2}$$
or
$$m=\frac{y_2}{x_2-b}$$

But, the question is, how you will find $b$ and $c$ first before using the the formula above?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the $y$ intercept, i.e., if you aready know the value of $c$, then yes, you can calculate $$m=\frac{y-c}{x}.$$ The formula $$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$ allows you to calculate $m$ when you know two points on the line. In other words, these are two different formulas for two different pairs of input parameters (in one case, the input is a point and the $y$ intercept, in the other, the input is a point and another point).

You can see, however, that the two formulas are quite closely connected. In fact, you can still use the *second* formula even if you know the $y$ intercept $c$ and a point $(x_2,y_2)$. You can do this becaues "knowing the $y$ intercept is $c$" is equivalent to "knowing that $(0,c)$ is a point on the line. So, if $c$ is the intercept, then if you set $x_1=0, y_1=c$, then $(x_1, y_1)$ is also on the line, which means the second formula gives us

$$m = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} = \frac{y_2 - c}{x_2 - 0} = \frac{y_2-c}{x_2}$$ which is your second equation.